# How do I create tab indenting in html

Tags: html, xhtml

I have a situation as follows

<body>
Test<br />
test<br />
test1<br />
</body>

I need to add a tab after the 2nd test and 3rd test

so that it looks similar to this.

Test
    test
                test1

Is there a special HTML entity or special character for TAB. eg. Non-breaking space == & nbsp ;

thanks

Comment: I think I'll settle with list and then use list-style-type: none; in css to hide the bullets

Comment: if you're settling on a list, why did you accept an answer that doesn't even mention lists?

Comment: Please, as one of the answers advises, update the question about the data structure being marked up. The presentation shouldn't be considered until the structure is known.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ye gods, tables?

Looks like an *obvious* use-case for lists, with variable margin and list-style-type: none; seasoned to taste.

Comment: It isn't obvious. The example given by the OP is too vague to tell if it is list data or something else.

Answer (score 26):

The simplest way I can think of would be to place the text in nested divs. Then add margin to the left of div. It will cascade down, giving you indentation.

```
<div id='testing'>
  Test1
  <div>
    Test2
    <div>
      Test3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the CSS:

```
#testing div {
  margin-left: 10px;/*or whatever indentation size you want*/
}
```

With those, you'll get a nice tree, no matter how many levels deep you want to go.

EDIT: You can also use `padding-left` if you want.

Comment: +1 For mentioning an infinite level depth. It could come in very handy, plus it would work better for dynamic content.

Comment: I say list over div, but at least that's a subjective conversation. +1

Comment: The question was to display tab characters in HTML pages, not how to fake them using CSS...

Comment: @Matthias - ridiculous concern, CSS is a more than reasonable assumption given HTML. Considerably less than 1% of your audience won't have CSS.

Comment: @annakata Lists are great, but for infinite depth, it is much easier to just throw in a div under the parent node. And xpath traversal is reduced as you no longer have to add `ul` all over the place.

@Mathias Bynens My answer is better at solving his problem than using tab characters.

Comment: ew divs - why not choose something that has semantics, maybe a list or a table, depending on the kind of data?

Comment: @annakata, a CSS solution more reasonable? That depends on the situation. Since the question was how to display tab _characters_, I'm guessing he actually wants to display the characters, not just indent some text. There is a big difference.

Comment: I have no idea why this or the list option is not the accepted answer - using a list or divs are clearly the best options.

Comment: @Jørn Schou-Rode: divs for simplicity

Answer (score 13):

If you really want to use **tabs** (== tabulator characters), you have to go with the following solution, which I don't recommend:

```
<pre>
test
&#x09;test
&#x09;&#x09;test
</pre>
```

or replace the `<pre/>` with `<div style="white-space: pre" />` to achieve the same effect as with the pre element. You can even enter a literal tab character instead of the escaped `&#x09;`.

I don't recommend it for most usages, because it is not really semantic, that is, from viewing the HTML source a program cannot deduce any useful information (like, e.g., "this is a heading" or such). You'd be better off using one of the nice `margin-left` examples of the other answers. However, if you'd like to display some stuff like source code or the such, the above solution would do it.

Cheers,

Answer (score 5):

See [Making a 'Tab' in HTML](http://nehasinha.wordpress.com/2008/01/31/making-a-tab-in-html/) by Neha Sinha:

> ### Preformatted
>
> You can put tab characters in your HTML directly if
>   you use what’s called “preformatted”
>   text.In HTML, surround text that you
>   want “preformatted” in a pair of
>   “`<pre>`” and “`</pre>`” start and end
>   tags.
>
> ### Tables
>
> You can use a html table so that everything you put within the set of rows(`<tr>`) and 
>   columns(`<td>`) shows up the same way. You can very well hide the table borders to show the text alone.
>
> ### Using the `<dd>` Tag
>
> The `<dd>` tag is for formatting definitions. But it
>   also will create a line break and make
>   a tab!
>
> ### `&nbsp;`, The Non-Breaking Space
>
> One bit of HTML code I used in the table example is the “non-breaking space,” encoded as   in HTML. This just gives you some space. Combined with a line break, `<br>`, you can create some tab-like effects.

### Example

```
Test<br/>
<pre>   </pre>test<br/>
<pre>       </pre>test1<br/>
```

this should render as:

```
Test
    test
        test1
```

Comment: pre is entirely unnecessary here, far better to add padding-left based on em units to nested elements

Comment: @annakata, there's more than one way to skin the cat on this one. I'd personally prefer the css way, but there could be situations that's an overkil, or simply not possible. pre I think is a quick hack.

Comment: This answer does not deserve to be accepted, especially since the asker didn't even use this method to solve his problem.

Comment: *DO NOT* use this answer as an accepted solution. The options of using pre, definition lists and/or non-breaking spaces is completely inappropriate for creating 'tabs'. George IV's answer is by far the most relevant.

Comment: Hey, give @annakata credit. That solution makes plenty of sense too.

Comment: I don't know why this solution has been downvoted. If you use an editor (in a web application) and you want to show the content afterwards in a regular div, pre is the way to go. Yes, you should use tables or lists (totally agreed with that!) but some users are stubborn and want to use a tab just like they do in Word... you could convert the tabs programmatically but this isn't always as easy as it sounds.

Answer (score 5):

There have been a variety of good and bad answers so far but it seems no-one has addressed the way that you can choose between the solutions.

The first question to ask is **"What is the relationship between the data being displayed?"**. Once this has been answered it the HTML structure you use should be obvious.

Please update the question explaining more about the structure of the content you need to display and you should find that you get better answers. At the moment everything from using `<pre>` to tables might be the best solution.

Comment: Best answer. There can be 10 or 15 correct solutions but OP did a very poor job maintaining quality in this question.

Answer (score 3):

I think that easiest thing to do is to use UL/LI html tags and then to manipulate (and remove if needed) symbols in front of list with CSS.

Then you get something like:

- Test
- Test2

  - Test 3

[More info + working example you can try out.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to display tabs (tabulator characters), use a `PRE` element (or any element with the `white-space: pre;` CSS applied to it).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   pre { white-space: pre; }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>This is a normal paragraph, blah blah blah.</p>
  <pre>This is preformatted text contained within a <code>PRE</code> element. Oh, and here are some tab characters, each of which are displayed between two arrows: ← → ← → ← → ← →</pre>
 </body>
</html>
```

You can also use the HTML entity `&#x09;` instead of the actual tab character.

Comment: Or any block element with `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: Doesn't the pre tag screw up a lot of formatting and force an ugly uniform character width font?

Comment: The code in the codeblocks on this site are in pre tags. Are they screwed up and ugly?

Comment: Ok, the first part is not helpful, but the &#x09; is a correct solution, so don't understand the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a fan of using CSS to simulate a Tab Character.
For Indenting, yes, by all means use CSS - but *not* for Tab Characters.

For a single Tab, I would replace with "`&nbsp; &nbsp;` " (4 Spaces).
This is similar to what was used to format your Question for display.
The added benefit to this is (if someone copies your text)
   it will preserve the spacing when pasted into Word or Notepad.

Example:

```html
Test<br />
&nbsp; &nbsp; test<br />
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; test1
```

Note: If your text is in a `<pre>` tag, then @Boldewyn's answer is the better option.
Keep in mind, the text in the `<pre>` tag may render differently than expected.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, however someone may want to use the following list in order to create an indented list (by using a *[description list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp)*)

---

In my opinion, this is a much cleaner way than many of the other answers here and may be the *best* way to go:

- It does not use a bunch of *whitespace characters* (which gives little control in terms of formatting for styles)
- It does not use the `<pre>` tag, which should only be used for formatting (in my opinion, this should pretty much be a last resort or a special-case use in HTML); `<pre>` tag is also whitespace-dependent and not CSS dependent when used the way it is intended to be used

  > [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) says to *use the `<pre>` element when displaying text with unusual formatting, or some sort of computer code*.
- *description lists* allow for more control in terms of formatting and hierarchy
- The answer by @geowa4, I would say, is another great way to accomplish this. `<div>`s allow for style control and, depending on use/objective, his answer may be the *best* way to go.

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Test</dt>
  <dd>
    <dl>
      <dt>test</dt>
      <dd>test1</dd>
    </dl>
  </dd>
</dl>
```