# Aligning two lines of horizontal links evenly with CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have 6 links, all different character lengths on two lines.  I need everything to align evenly.  Like this:

```
Home       About Us     Location
Contact    Visit        Schedule
```

I imagine the way to do this is to make the `li` a specific width and then apply an appropriate margin to the right side, but for some reason I can't apply a width.  If I have the following html skeleton, how would I edit the CSS to accomplish this?  I've looked around the web for a solution, but I've haven't found any similar questions because my menu sits on two separate lines.

```html
<div class="footer">
 <ul id="footerlinks">
  <li><a href="link 1">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="link 2">About Us </a></li>
  <li><a href="link 3">Location</a></li>
<br>
  <li><a href="link4">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="link5">Visit</a></li>
  <li><a href="link6">Schedule</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the width of `<ul>` and `<li>`. And remove the `<br />` it makes the markup invalid.

HTML

```
<ul id="footerlinks">
  <li><a href="link 1">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="link 2">About Us </a></li>
  <li><a href="link 3">Location</a></li>
  <li><a href="link4">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="link5">Visit</a></li>
  <li><a href="link6">Schedule</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```css
#footerlinks { width: 300px; }
#footerlinks li { width: 100px; display: inline-block; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jBPmF/)

[Demo(with white-space fix)](http://jsfiddle.net/jBPmF/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Give the li elements a display property of inline-block and a width. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4XuZ/) to demonstrate:

```
li { display: inline-block; width: 100px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
<pre>
test
&#x09;test
&#x09;&#x09;test
</pre>
```

Source: [How do I create tab indenting in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068647/how-do-i-create-tab-indenting-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

First, a `<br/>` is not a valid child element of `<ul/>`.

To apply a width to an `<li/>`, you will need to make it a block-level element.

```
<ul id="footerlinks">
  <li><a href="link 1">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="link 2">About Us </a></li>
  <li><a href="link 3">Location</a></li>
  <li><a href="link4">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="link5">Visit</a></li>
  <li><a href="link6">Schedule</a></li>
</ul>​
```

and

```
#footerlinks {
    background:#ccc;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:5px;
    width:300px;
}

#footerlinks li {
    float:left;
    padding:5px 0;
    width:33%;
}​
```

Here is a working example - http://jsfiddle.net/jaredhoyt/xbvyP/